# C joining two character devices

Tags: c, linux, kernel, pipe, dup

I've two devices one is a pts (`/dev/pts/N`) another is a socket(`/path/to/socket`). I want infinitely read the pts and write that to socket, and infinitely read socket and write to pts.

What I am doing right now is to open both and create a read loop in two threads, But is there any simpler way with pipe that takes some works in kernel space ?

Comment: You may use `select()` and do the job in one thread. Anyway, most of the time your program will be blocked inside a `wait_event` loop inside the kernel.

Comment: Only in one direction

Comment: would it be much different in terms of performance or manageability ?

Comment: There is already tool for that: [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/). Just in case you need tool not the implementation.

Comment: Though I need a programmatic solution. How would I do the same with socat ? `socat /dev/pts/N UNIX:socket` didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "didn't work"? Also, note that if `/dev/pts/X` is opened by someone else (like `xterm`) you will compete for reading with that process.

Comment: Yes it worked, I had to use `raw` But I want a programmatic solution. because in some cases I need to concatenate some pts or select one of them and then send to socket. also I need to have a rest interface.